# Compare arrays from mysql-colums then insert something in each row with same colum-array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, insert

### **The situation:**

A mysql-table has three columns `Name`, `Areas` and `Type`
`Name` contains one customer
`Areas` contains an array of locations (area1,area2,area3...)
`Type` is empty for now

**If helpfull or needed:**

All names(count: can vary) and areas(count: 50) are known, but the composition is unknown and can vary for each name

### **The goal:**

To select the `Name` where all `Areas` are the same and then insert a letter in the `Type` column

`ID` = 1; `Name` = Name1; `Areas` = area1,area2;
`ID` = 2; `Name` = Name2; `Areas` = area1,area2,area3;
`ID` = 3; `Name` = Name3; `Areas` = area1,area2;
`ID` = 4; `Name` = Name4; `Areas` = area5,area8,area2,area4
`ID` = 5; `Name` = Name4; `Areas` = area6;

Name1 and Name3 `Type` = A
Name2 `Type` = B
Name4`Type` = C
Name5 `Type` = D

**Things tryed so far**

searching (found a few good ways to get close)
multi_array_search
get same values from array
crying in a corner and hope to find a solution
But it all fails when the arrays should check against each other for the areas.

Tryed foreach(x as xy) and then for ($i = 0; $i < count(xy); $i++)
Maybe just this code is needed?

But nothing really worked out the way needed.

Any help is appreciated =)

If already asked sorry but I found nothing that really helped or searched/looked for the wrong terms.

Comment: Don't use comma-separated values in SQL tables. Normalize your data.

Comment: What if you run out of letters of the alphabet?

Comment: When Z then AA, AB, AC...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT id, areas
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY areas
```

Then in the PHP code, test when the `areas` value changes, and increment the `type`.

```
$type = '';
$last_areas = null;
$update_stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE YourTable SET type = :type WHERE id = :id");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($row['areas'] != $last_areas) {
        $type = next_type($type);
        $last_areas = $row['areas'];
    }
    $update_stmt->execute(array(':type' => $type, ':id' => $row['id']));
}

function next_type($cur_type) {
    if ($cur_type == '') {
        return 'A';
    }
    $last_letter = substr($cur_type, -1);
    if ($last_letter = 'Z') {
        $new_letter = 'A';
        if (strlen($cur_type) == 1) {
            $first_letter = 'A';
        } else {
            $first_letter = chr(ord($cur_type[0]) + 1);
        }
        return $first_letter . $new_letter;
    } else {
        $new_letter = chr(ord($last_letter) + 1);
        if (strlen($cur_type) == 1) {
            return $new_letter;
        } else {
            return $cur_type[0] . $new_letter;
        }
    }
}
```

This `next_type` function works as long as you don't have to go to 3 letters in the type.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've tryed it but I get a Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_result() on null. When i got that fixed I gonna try it again.